# Qiskit textbook: mod 15 multiplication circuit

Tags: qiskit, shors-algorithm, modular-exponentiation, period-finding-algorithm

The [Qiskit textbook](https://qiskit.org/textbook/ch-algorithms/shor.html#3.-Qiskit-Implementation) shows a circuit for mod 15 multiplication by "a", which for a==2 does the following operations:

```
U.swap(0,1)
U.swap(1,2)
U.swap(2,3)
```

But this is equivalent to a circular right-shift by 1 which is division (not multiplication) by 2.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that this is indeed an issue and [has been reported](https://github.com/qiskit-community/qiskit-textbook/issues/1462) to the qiskit-textbook project on GitHub.