# Qiskit textbook: Shor's algorithm

Tags: qiskit, shors-algorithm, quantum-phase-estimation

The [Qiskit textbook](https://qiskit.org/textbook/ch-algorithms/shor.html#3.-Qiskit-Implementation) shows the following circuit for implementing the phase $(\frac{s}{r})$ estimation stage of Shor's algorithm for factorizing 15:
[image]

My understanding is that the register of qubits 8-11 should be initialized to the state $|1\rangle$ which is the sum over $s \in \{0, .., r-1\}$ of the eigenstates$\frac{1}{\sqrt r}\sum_{k=0}^{r-1}e^{-\frac{2\pi i s k}{r}}|a^k \mod N\rangle$ of the modular multiplication operator $U|y\rangle = |ay \mod N \rangle$.

But the 4-qubit representation of $|1\rangle$ is $|0001\rangle$ and not $|1000\rangle$. 
So, shouldn't we set $q_8$ (the lsb of the modular exponentiation circuits) to 1 instead of $q_{11}$?

Comment: Thanks for spotting this problem. Can you please report this as an issue on the textbook repo so that we can correct it? Thank you. https://github.com/qiskit-community/qiskit-textbook/issues/new?assignees=&labels=content+bug&template=content-problem---.yaml&title=%5BChapter-number%5D

Comment: It has already been reported: https://github.com/qiskit-community/qiskit-textbook/issues/1462

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you're correct and this is an inconsistency in the textbook. Since they initialize the state backwards but also do the modular multiplication backwards (as you also [pointed out](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/27539/qiskit-textbook-mod-15-multiplication-circuit)), it seems like they are consistently inconsistent and so it doesn't affect the results, but should be fixed for consistency/clarity.